# ArcGIS Server Error: “Feature service requires a registered database”

Tags: arcgis-server, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, error-00090

I'm attempting to publish a feature service to ArcGIS server. I'm running PostgreSQL and ArcSDE. When I try to publish the service I get the error "00090: Feature service requires a registered database". When I validate the database registration it appears to succeed, but I still can't publish the service. The features I am publishing are located inside of the geodatabase that I am registering. This geodatabase is located on the same server that ArcGIS Server resides. Am I missing something ?

[image]

Comment: I believe that when you register a database you need to use the same connection as the layers in your feature service use.  Using different connections to the same geodatabase I think it sees it as different databases

Comment: You need to provide more details.  The username and hostname and database must be IDENTICAL between the connection doing the publishing and the connection which is registered (it's a simple concatenated string compare).  The published service also needs to have the password remembered, because connections don't remember the username without the password.